# Unit testing chained constructors

Tags: c#, unit-testing

When "chaining" constructors, should all unit tests that are run on the first constructor also be run on the second constructor (in addition to those that are unique to the second)?

I can see the benefit of being rigorous but trivial duplication of a large number of (simple) tests seems unnecessary. Having said that, the duplicated tests are only trivial for as long as `: this(a, b)` is present.

In the general case, it feels like I shouldn't be writing loads of unit tests that hinge on something trivial that will never change.

```
      public MyObject(double a, double b)
      {
         // Do some minor calculations, initialise some properties
         Property1 = a * b;
         Property2 = Property1;
      }

      public MyObject(double a, double b, double c) 
         : this(a, b)
      {
         // Set more properties
         Property2 = (a * b) + c;
      }

      public double Property1
      {
         get;
      }

      public double Property2
      {
         get;
      }
```

Comment: Depends!  Base the decision on your own situation and balance of risk vs. effort.  I tend to avoid dogmatic 100% coverage unless it's absolutely necessary.  This is very opinion-based, *in my opinion*.

Comment: I am sure that those properties are used/tested via tests of behaviour which consumes them. The you don't need to test this properties seprately.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I agree with what has been said here.